# Should we Include spaces in Huffman Coding method

Tags: algorithm, huffman-code

When we encode using huffman coding method.Should we include spaces into consideration as well?

Comment: Spaces are just characters, so these are encoded exactly the same way (just like all other characters, like `~`, `@`, `!`, etc.)

Comment: Why would you omit any character?  That only adds complication. And makes it impossible to decompress to 100% the same text.

Comment: Ifyouleaveoutthespacesitwillbehardtoreadthedecompressedtext.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [*Huffman coding* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) encodes a stream of characters. These characters can include spaces, symbols, emoji characters, characters with diacritics, etc.

So we take spaces into account as well, otherwise if we would decode the string, the decoded string will not contain these spaces anymore.

In fact the Wikipedia article contains an image of a Huffman encoding tree that shows a space, at the righmost leaf:

[image: Huffman encoding image on Wikipedia]